# How can I detect if a file of associated type has started my application? vb.net

Tags: vb.net, inno-setup, associated-types

I am using inno setup and I made an associated file type so that my app starts when a user double clicks an associated file. But how can I know if the application was started by a file so I can show the file?
For now, my app simply starts running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filename is the first argument passed to your Application. You can (and must) handle it, there are several ways to access this in .net, e.g. with [Environment.GetCommandLineArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: So I don't have to do something in inno setup script to pass the name to my application?

Comment: I don't know inno setup - I thought that the association is already setup up correctly (double-click on a file opens your application). If that is the case, the file is (in all likelihood) already passed to your app as an argument.

Comment: In Inno Setup you just need to make sure the registry entry for the Shell open command contains the `%1` portion. Just like it's shown in [`this FAQ`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isfaq.php#assoc).

Comment: Thanks! the file name was the first argument!